# Why is a discriminant needed for type guards of union types?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

In the code below, why is `typeof data.x === 'string'` type guard insufficient to distinguish the union type?

[TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IB4C5kDOYUoA5gDTICe+IArgLYBG0yAvgLABQoksiKAEKYctRiyiUahYmXbduMOiARhgAexDIAFnBAATADbQAFPrhg4+dAB9kggJSZuyV8mAxkJsFQAOEdU9zSwA6bGQAXijkAHIiEhBSGKcMFzd04LgQqmQAelyZBNJkO3pmVgBaKuQAdQAJAFUAFQB+NNdOLk7ufOQAd2AwbWR9YAIEEgZQPTAFHnBoeCQ0ACYRAGtQfXwY1BjKPEKyKTFyqHl5viWhNaxNgx3BfdFkMokTo8SLxWVVDS1dAZjFAVmYLFZViV7CsUu13J4waF7vpItFdslnFx0hlwdk8gU3tA4Z02EA)

```
interface A { x: string, y: number }
interface B { x: number, y: string }

function handler(data: A | B) {
    if (typeof data.x === 'string') {
        data.y // string | number --- WHUT?
    }
}
```

In what case could `handler` be called with the (invalid) shape `{ x: string: y: string }`?

Using a discriminant, it works (why?):

```
interface A { kind: 'A', x: string, y: number }
interface B { kind: 'B', x: number, y: string }

function handler(data: A | B) {
    if (data.kind === 'A') {
        data.y // number
    }
}
```

Reading offic docs on [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) doesn't help.

They only state:

> Some languages automatically discriminate unions for you; TypeScript instead builds on JavaScript patterns as they exist today.

That doesn't explain why TS can work with similar type guards in some cases, while not in the case of a union (I don't see any ambiguity in my first example).

Comment: The discriminant should be *unique*: in the example that's correct you use the string literals 'A' and 'B' but in your original example (if you're thinking of the x property as the discriminant) you're just using string. In other words, your first example isn't actually a discriminated union in the TS type system.

Comment: I understand it's not a discriminated union (which by definition needs a discriminant). My question is, why does it need one -- i.e. why do I need to make it into a discriminated union? Why is my original type guard not enough?

Comment: Only discriminated unions let you narrow an object of a union type to an object of one of its constituents by checking one of its properties.  You are trying to narrow `A | B` to `A` by checking the `x` property, which would only work if `A | B` were a discriminated union and if `x` were its discriminant.  But they're not, so you can't.

Comment: Yea, but that's circular reasoning. The [true answer is](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506#issuecomment-474858198) --- it's not implemented because of motivation/time/performance constraints, not soundness.

Comment: I think the communication issue here is because you're asking "why do I need to make this into a discriminated union?" instead of "why doesn't TS consider this to be a discriminated union?"  The former question invites answers like "you want a discriminated union because you're trying to discriminate a union based on one of its properties; that's what a discriminated union *is*", wheres the latter question invites answers like "lack of performance/motivation/time to implement this particular pattern".

Comment: To my knowledge, I didn't ask anywhere about trying to go for discriminated unions (just cited them, and their use of discriminants, as a solution). But I'll try to make my language even less ambiguous in future questions. Thanks. (edit: true, I used `discriminated-union` tag, which might have given off the wrong vibe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discriminated unions need to have a very particular structure. I once dug up the rules [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506#issuecomment-474802840):

> Narrowing the parent object is only done in specific scenarios, when the property is considered a discriminant for the union. A property is considered as a discriminant property if:
>
> - The property is a literal type as outlined here [#9163](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163)
> - The a property of a union type to be a discriminant property if it has a union type containing at least one unit type and no instantiable types as outlined here [#27695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27695)

If those rules are not followed you just end up with a field discrimination not a parent object discrimination.

Comment: Thanks, but why do I need a discriminant in the first place? (I don't need it to be a discriminated union in its true sense). Ok, got my answer reading the rest of the GH issue: **because**. Can you edit your answer to include that, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @dwelle  yeah.. because .. it is just implemented that way ..